# Wait for macro triggered by incoming mail to finish, before repeating on next incoming mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I  have a macro that is triggered every time I receive an e-mail with a certain subject name.

If I receive multiple e-mails at the same time that trigger the macro, Outlook will either freeze and crash or the macro will run just for the last e-mail received.

Is there

i) a configuration in Outlook that puts a delay between e-mails arriving at the Inbox, creating a backlog of e-mails to enter the Inbox, giving time for the macro to run all the way through?

or

ii) a VBA code so the macro runs after the current macro that is running finishes?

Answer (score 1):

Possible alternatives are listed below:

- Handle the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the `Applications` class. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously.
- Use a timer to run your custom VBA code periodically. VBA doesn't provide anything for that, but you may use Windows API functions as listed below:

```
Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerfunc As Long) As Long
Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Public TimerID As Long 'Need a timer ID to eventually turn off the timer. If the timer ID <> 0 then the timer is running

Public Sub ActivateTimer(ByVal nMinutes As Long)
  nMinutes = nMinutes * 1000 * 60 'The SetTimer call accepts milliseconds, so convert to minutes
  If TimerID <> 0 Then Call DeactivateTimer 'Check to see if timer is running before call to SetTimer
  TimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, nMinutes, AddressOf TriggerTimer)
  If TimerID = 0 Then
    MsgBox "The timer failed to activate."
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub DeactivateTimer()
Dim lSuccess As Long
  lSuccess = KillTimer(0, TimerID)
  If lSuccess = 0 Then
    MsgBox "The timer failed to deactivate."
  Else
    TimerID = 0
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub TriggerTimer(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idevent As Long, ByVal Systime As Long)
  MsgBox "The TriggerTimer function has been automatically called!"
End Sub
```

- The most reliable and best option is to create a COM add-in instead where you will be able to use multithreading by using a low-level API - Extended MAPI. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) to get started quickly.

Answer (score 0):

All macros run on the main Outlook thread, so they are always executed sequentially.

But the script triggered by a rule should not take too long to execute - otherwise you will miss the notifcations and the UI will become unresponsive. There isn't much you can do in VBA alone - you can't create secondary threads, and even if you could, OOM objects cannot be accessed on secondary threads - you'd need to use either Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or Redemption (any language).